# Change the value of $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en') from controller

Tags: angularjs, translate, angular-translate

I was trying to change the value of preferred language on click of a button. But I can't access the translateProvider from the the controller. How to change the value of $translateProvider.preferredLanguage() from an event in controller?

```
.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {
    'TITLE': 'Title in English',
  });

  $translateProvider.translations('lo', {
    'TITLE': 'Title in Local language',
  });

  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
}]);
```

I don't want to fetch data from JSON i am writing every response inside the config file. Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you want to change the _preferred_ language? Usually you just inject $translate and then use $translate.use(newLanguage); to switch the language.

Comment: yep i missed it my bad :D . @StephenFriedrich

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inject $translate in your controller.

```
// controller
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $translate){
    $translate.use("yourlangcode"); // load your desired locale by lang code so 'en', 'lo'
}
```